# how to style php echo output

Tags: php, css

It's probably stupid question, but I can not find an answer. How can I style echo output with css? I have this code:

```
echo "<div id="errormsg"> Error </div>";
```

Now it displays syntax error, I think because of those quotes around errormsg. I've tried single quotes, but with no effect. Thank you

Comment: you shouldn't have accepted the answer that you did, this was originally a CSS question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try

```
echo "<div id=\"errormsg\"> Error </div>";
```

Comment: This shouldn't have been marked as the answer, as the question was about CSS styling

Answer (score 16):

When outputting HTML, it's easier to use single quotes so you can use proper double quotes inside like so:

```
echo '<div id="errormsg"> Error </div>';
```

That will get rid of your parse error... To edit the style you will need to use CSS with the selector of `#errormsg` like so:

```
#errormsg {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First you need to either use single-quotes to surround the attribute value:

```
echo "<div id='errormsg'> Error </div>";
```

Or you could reverse that, to give:

```
echo '<div id="errormsg"> Error </div>';
```

Or you should escape the quotes:

```
echo "<div id=\"errormsg\"> Error </div>";
```

And then style the resulting element with the CSS:

```
#errormsg {
    /* css */
}
```

The syntax problem you were encountering is a result of terminating the string and then having a disparate element between the first and second strings, with which PHP has no idea what to do.

Answer (score 2):

To put double quotes inside of a double-quoted string, you need to "escape" them by putting blackslashes before them:

```
echo "<div id=\"errormsg\"> Error </div>";
```

In this case, another choice is to use single quotes for one or the other.

```
echo "<div id='errormsg'> Error </div>";
echo '<div id="errormsg"> Error </div>';
```

PHP's documentation has [a section explaining the different string syntaxes](https://www.php.net/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax), which should explain everything you could want to know about this subject.

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes around `errormsg` and what you have should work just fine.  Alternatively, but less tidy, you can escape the double quotes with a backslash.

```
echo "<div id='errormsg'> Error </div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a syntax error because you are including unescaped double quotes inside a string that is delimited by double quotes.

Either escape them

```
echo "<div id=\"errormsg\"> Error </div>";
```

or use single quotes

```
echo '<div id="errormsg"> Error </div>';
```

The browser doesn't care if you generated markup using `echo` or something else. It just sees the HTML you send to it.

For the above markup, you can style it using an id selector:

```
#errormsg { /* … */ }
```

The usual rules for the cascade (including specificity) will apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to care about *single quotes or double quotes* then the better way to achieve your answer is to use **heredoc syntax** .
Your solution :

```
<?php
$heredoc = <<< EOT
<div id="errormsg">Error solved</div>
EOT;
echo "$heredoc";
?>
```

css : 
`#errormsg{color: green;}` 
**WARNING :**

1. Do not add whiteSpace after `<<< EOT`
2. Do not add whiteSpace before `EOT`;
3. Do not add whiteSpace between `EOT` and `;`
4. Do not add whiteSpace after `EOT;`
5. `EOT;` must be in new line.