# CSS Styling in PHP echo

Tags: php, html, css

I am very new to using PHP and I am unsure how to style this table. I created a class but I am not sure if I make the changes in a separate CSS file because this did not work for me.

Do I use style tags? How can I do this?

```
//call function to get all the users or potential friends 
$friend_options = getUserForFriends();
//output of the options is in a table
print '<table class = "users"><form action="friends.php" method="post">';
print $friend_options;
print '</form></table>';
```

Comment: You can use a style tag or separate file. Either can work. If you had a problem, show the CSS you used

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is this output located? PHP is rendered by the server before the browser reads it. So as long as the code is echoed on a page with a linked CSS file with styling for your `.users { }`  class table, you should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure the css file is linked in that php file. you can declare html doc under and link the css their

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
 print '<table class = "users" id="userStyling"><form action="friends.php" method="post">';
```

To edit the style you will need to use CSS with the selector of `#userStyling` like so:

```
#userStyling{
    color: red;
}
```

[how to style php echo output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7147609/how-to-style-php-echo-output)

Comment: Why couldn't they just use the class `users`? There's no reason to introduce an `id`.

Comment: yeah that too this is only an idea